# Slicing lists imported from CSV files

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of 156 elements (all integers) in a CSV file. I'm importing the list using the following code:

```
    with open("rayuela-chapter-list.txt") as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        x = [row for row in r]
```

When I try to slice the list I get the errors like the one below:

```
    x[14]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

When it does not give me an error it returns the entire list, no matter how I slice it.

If I'm importing a CSV file, how do I make sure that I can slice the resulting list? is there anything I'm missing in the code?

Comment: What does `print x` show?

Comment: It shows all elements in the list

Comment: What does that look like? Are there at least 15 of them?

Comment: If your csv is comma-separated, you'll have just one row and x[14] doesn't exist. So, the question is - is data stored in csv as a row or as a column?

Comment: @wooble There are more than 15 values. It prints 156

Comment: @sashkello, they are stored as columns, storing them as individual rows make no sense for the application I'm working on.

Comment: @caraya Mate, clarify your question. 1. "they are stored as columns" - what does it mean? Each number in individual column, or all numbers one under another? 2. What EXACTLY do you see printed for x? Just show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list is stored in csv as a row, you are reading this whole row in one take. Basically, this line

```
x = [row for row in r]
```

will return

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,......]]
```

If there would be more rows, it would be a list of lists, but in your case, it is a list of one list. To get what you need, just do:

```
x = x[0]
```

Comment: I ended up adding a second variable so now the code looks like this:

`with open("rayuela-chapter-list.csv") as f:
 r = csv.reader(f)
 x = [row for row in r]
 z = x[0]
`

If I query z[0] I get the value I was expecting to begin with. I don't quite understand why.

Comment: @caraya I just explained this in my answer... And you don't need another variable. Just reassign `x` as I show.

Comment: Thank you for the additional feedback. I missed something on the explanation.